# CSS not loading for React Foundation Apps

Tags: javascript, css, zurb-foundation, reactjs

I have installed React Foundation Apps according to the docs:
http://webrafter.com/opensource/react-foundation-apps/install

I had to fiddle with the webpack.config.js file to make it parse .jsx files but now the module is working, except that no CSS is added. I'm trying to use the Modal but it just shows up on the page with no styling applied.

What can I have missed?

Comment: Did you post an issue? https://github.com/akiran/react-foundation-apps

Comment: I did but I haven't go any response for a few days.

Comment: You haven't provided much information here with no steps to replicate the issue you're seeing (*"I had to fiddle with..."*). Why not just load the CSS file directly and avoid using webpack for now for this?

Comment: I removed the line: `exclude: /node_modules/` for the .jsx loader in webpack.

I'm thinking I'm missing a SCSS loader and installed sass-loader and added it as a loader in webpack.config.js:

`{
   test: /\.scss$/,
   loader: "style!css!sass"
}`

..but with no luck.